# Numpy array into multidimensional slices at different indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a numpy array and integer `x`, is there a way to create a multi-dimensional numpy array where each row is a slice of the original array starting from index `0 ... x` without hard-coding? For example, if `x = 3`:

```
array = np.arange(10)
output = np.array([array, array[1:], array[2:], array[3:]])
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense creating `np.array` of differently sized arrays, but you can use `np.array([array[i:] for i in range(x+1)])`.

Comment: Show the `output`.  Is that a multidimensional array?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to form a Hankel matrix, luckily `scipy` has a built in function for that: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html